# Use javascript to hide element based on ALT TAG only?

Tags: javascript

I have a wordpress site, and a plugin uses cufon text replacement. (I'm not entirely sure the actual way it does this, but it's not important).

I'd like to use a "display:none" on only a specific word or two. For example, on the mobile theme, I'd like to change "Contact Us" to only "Contact". The only way to hide this on the fly is by using the alt tag since there is no class or ID.

So can I use JavaScript to detect the alt tag "Us" and do a display:none? Sample code below.

```
<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Us" style="width: 20px; height: 14px; "><canvas width="32" height="17" style="width: 32px; height: 17px; top: -2px; left: -2px; "></canvas><cufontext>Us</cufontext></cufon>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the tag of element your searching for (I assume you have this information) you can look up all those tags in the document and check the alt attribute value. When you find the particular element you're searching for you can do what ever you please with it. In this example I changed the `textContent` property.

```
(function () {
  var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

  for ( var i = 0, length = li.length; i < length; i++ )
  {
    if ( li[i].getAttribute('alt') === 'two' ) 
      li[i].textContent = 'New Text';
  }

}).call(this);
```

Live: http://jsbin.com/ixitut/2/edit

You can also narrow the scope of this search by instead changing `document` to be a more specific tag.

```
var searchWithin = document.getElementById(/**/)
var tags = searchWithin.getElementsByTagName(/**/)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName

Comment: This is the exact output code: `<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Us" style="width: 20px; height: 14px; "><canvas width="32" height="17" style="width: 32px; height: 17px; top: -2px; left: -2px; "></canvas><cufontext>Us</cufontext></cufon>` and I couldn't get yours working with this.

Comment: Update @travis, I got it on the test site with this code. `(function () {
  var li = document.getElementsByTagName('cufon');
  
  for ( var i = 0, length = li.length; i < length; i++ )
  {
    if ( li[i].getAttribute('alt') === 'Us' ) 
      li[i].textContent = '';
  }
     
}).call(this);`

Answer (score 0):

We assume you are talking about images, since that's the only place `alt` attributes are relevant.

Using [`.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute) on all the `cufon` tags, you can match the string `Us`:

```
var cufons = document.getElementsByTagName("cufon");
// Loop over and look for the attr
var num = cufons.length;
for (var i=0; i<num; i++) {
  // If it has an alt attr and matches Us inside word boundaries...
  if (cufons[i].getAttribute('alt') && /\bUs\b/.test(cufons[i].getAttribute('alt'))) {
    // set to display:none
    cufons[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's not an image, it's cufon.

`<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Us" style="width: 20px; height: 14px; "><canvas width="32" height="17" style="width: 32px; height: 17px; top: -2px; left: -2px; "></canvas><cufontext>Us</cufontext></cufon>`

Comment: Then just replace the img in document.getElementsByTagName with cufon

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the `text` of an `<a href="...">Contact Us</a>` tag to `Contact` and to identify that `link` you need to use a flag and in that case I think you can use `rel attribute`, i.e.

```
​<a href="#" rel="us">Contact Us</a>
```

and javascript to change `Contact Us` to `Contact` you can use the following code

```
​var links=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++)
{
    var rel=links[i].getAttribute('rel');
    if(rel && rel.match(/^us$/i)) links[i].innerHTML='Contact';
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/yGzhh/1/).

Alternatively without using any attribute you can just check the `innerHTML` of the `a tag` and if it contains `Contact US` then change it to `Contact` as follows

```
<a href="#">Contact Us</a>
```

and javascript to change `Contact Us` to `Contact` you can use the following code

```
var links=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++)
{
    var rel=links[i].innerHTML;
    if(rel && rel.match(/^Contact Us$/i)) links[i].innerHTML='Contact';
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/yGzhh/2/).

**Update:**

I think by default you can keep your `link text as Contact` instead of `Contact Us` and check if not in any mobile device (when in a desktop browser) then change the `Contact` to `Contact Us` using `javascript`, i.e.

```
var ismobile=navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)/i); // May be these are not enough but only an example
if(!ismobile){
    // one of above code snippets
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sheikh. I couldn't get it because I can't change the text like you asked. Here is the original source code `<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Us" style="width: 20px; height: 14px; "><canvas width="32" height="17" style="width: 32px; height: 17px; top: -2px; left: -2px; "></canvas><cufontext>Us</cufontext></cufon>`