# Do an action based on presence of ALT attribute with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, alt

I have some javascript which looks at the body and finds words and if one is present, it outputs a div. This is useful for many things, however...

What I need to do is also look at the body and all the ALT tags for the page as well.

I found this: [Use javascript to hide element based on ALT TAG only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677979/use-javascript-to-hide-element-based-on-alt-tag-only)
Which seems to change the ALT attribute, however I want to perform an action.

Here's my JS so far.

```
var bodytext = $('body').text();
    if(bodytext.toLowerCase().indexOf('one' || 'two')==-1)

return; 
    var elem = $("<div>Text Here</div>");
```

Thank you.

P.S. I am a N00B/ relatively new at JS, I am doing this for a small project, so I am not sure where to start for this in terms of JS functions.

Comment: Perhaps I can export attributes to and then check the console log?

Comment: More info: What I would like to do is have a selection of words that are 'scanned' for by JS, if one of those words is in any of the ALT tags on the page, the image is changed.

_I am trying to make a 'image blocker' for a phobia a friend of mine has. What I want to do is search all image attributes, meta tags and video tags and overlay the image or video or entire page with my own message._

This will be part of a Chrome extension.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**
Try this out, I commented the code to explain it a bit.

```
// build array of triggers
var triggers = ['trigger1','trigger2','trigger3'];

// wait for page to load
$(function() {

    // show loading overlay
    $('body').append('<div id="mypluginname-overlay" style="height:100%;width:100%;background-color:#FFF;"></div>');

    // check page title
    var $title = $('head title');
    for(trigger of triggers) {
        if($($title).innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(trigger) >= 0) {
            $($title).innerHTML = '*censored*'; 
        }
    }

    // check all meta
    $('meta').each(function() {
        var $meta = $(this);
        for(trigger of triggers) {
            if($($meta).attr('name').toLowerCase().indexOf(trigger) >= 0) {
                censorPage();
                return; //stop script if entire page must be censored
            } else if($($meta).attr('content').toLowerCase().indexOf(trigger) >= 0) {
                censorPage();
                return; //stop script if entire page must be censored
            }
        }
    });

    // check all img
    $('img').each(function() {
        var $img = $(this);
        for(trigger of triggers) {
            if($($img).attr('alt').toLowerCase().indexOf(trigger) >= 0) {
                censor($img);
            }
        }
    });

    // check all video
    $('video').each(function() {
        var $video = $(this);
        for(trigger of triggers) {
            if($($video).attr('alt').toLowerCase().indexOf(trigger) >= 0) {
                censor($video);
            }
        }
    });

    // if you want to be extra careful and check things like background image name,
    // you'll have to run this code here - very inefficent
    // but necessary if you want to check every single element's background image name:
    for($element of $('body').children()) {
        for(trigger of triggers) {
            if($($element).css('background-image').toLowerCase().indexOf(trigger) >= 0) {
                $($element).css('background-image','');
            }
        }   
    }

, function() { // Not sure if this is totally correct syntax, but use a callback function to determine when
               // when the rest of the script has finished running
        // hide overlay
        $('#mypluginname-overlay').fadeOut(500);
    }});

function censor($element) {
    // just a basic example, you'll probably want to make this more complex to overlay it properly
    $element.innerHTML = 'new content';
}

function censorPage() {
    // just a basic example, you'll probably want to make this more complex to overlay it properly
    $('body').innerHTML = 'new content';
}
```

**---Original Answer---**
I'm not sure exactly what you would like to do here, you should add more detail.  However if you choose to use jQuery, it provides tons of useful methods including the method .attr(), which lets you get the value of any attribute of any element.

Example:

```
var alt = $('#my-selector').attr('alt');
if (alt == 'whatYouWant') {
  alert('yay');
} else {
  alert('nay');
}
```

Comment: please see my more infor above :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery lib, you could select elements by attribute like:

```
   $('[alt="one"]').each(function(el){
        // do something
        var x = $(el).arrt('alt');
    });
```

If you use selector `$('[alt]')` you can get elements that have this attribute set, and then check the value of the element if you have a more complicated selection.

Than you have to change your return, as you could not put a div inside an ALT tag, it didn't work.

Here is about what is your expected output.

UPDATE

---

As you want to change all images and video in a page, the way to do this with jquery is through `$.replaceWith()`:

```
$('img,video').replaceWith($('<div>Text Here</div>'));
```

If you need to filter the elements:

```
$('img,video').each(function(el){
    if($(el).prop('tagName') == 'IMG' &&
       $(el).attr('alt') == 'the text...') {
           $(el).replaceWith($('<div>Text Here</div>'));
       }
})
```

But I'm not an expert on Chrome Extensions, I just put this code here in jQuery, as you was using jQuery.

Of course it could be done, with much code with plain javascript and the DOM API.

Comment: please see my more infor above :)